# Java PATH issues

Tags: java, windows, path

I tried to compile a java file and I got the "javac isn't recognized as an internal or external command" error. Last week it worked just fine.

The PATH variable seems to have been modified by something. I've tried changing it back to the correct address (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin), but it doesn't seem to reset. When I go into cmd and type `Echo %PATH%`, I get the following message.

`C:\WinAVR-20100110\bin;C:\WinAVR-20100110\utils\bin;set PATH="C:\WinAVR-20100110
\bin;C:\WinAVR-20100110\utils\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin"`

How should I change the PATH variable?

Comment: Have you restarted your `cmd` once you change the path variable?

Comment: and how you compile file?

Comment: In Windows system settings: http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx

Comment: Issue solved. Forgot to restart cmd after changing it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set PATH="C:\WinAVR-20100110 \bin;`

this looks suspicious.

The system goes through all your paths in the `PATH` till it finds javac. If not, it will tell you that javac is not recognized.
As a test, I suggest you move the path to Java bin to the start of PATH variable and see if that helps.

You change the path variable through Advanced System Settings.  You can find the steps here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Answer (score 0):

The path-entry `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin` looks like there's a jre7 installed on your computer. Could it be that someone accidentially replaced the jdk with a jre when installing the latest version? Is the jdk still there?

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because the command prompt cant find the java compiler.To solve this just add the path of the compiler to system path.You can add that by going to MyComputer->Properties->Advanced system settings->Environment variables and add the path to PATH variable
The javac can be found at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The presence of `WinAVR-20100110` is conspicuous; the WinAVR installer seems to be known to clobber the system-wide path. https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/winavr-deleted-contents-my-path-environment-variable

Comment: Perhaps the literal `SET` command in the middle of the questioner's `PATH` is a hint as to how the clobbering is happening...